# Remove all white space from text

Tags: xslt

I have an TEI-xml file that consists of the more or less typical elements.
I want to output the normalized version of a text without any white spaces etc.

my XSL for doing so consists of these lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tei ="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs tei"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="tei:note" />
    <xsl:template match="tei:orig" >
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="tei:text/tei:body//text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
    </xsl:template>
```

So it takes the text of the body and creates a copy of it, while it applies an empty template for `<note>` and `<orig>` - elements. The output looks just fine, but I have the TEI-immanent indentations and further white spaces in my text.

I thought the line `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` would take care of this, apparently not.

How can I remove all the white spaces in a TEI-XML?
(google and stackoverflow solutions didn't work so far :-( )

Comment: Please show a minimal but representative input sample together with the output sample you want and the one you currently get. Also tell us how/with which tool exactly you run the transformation.

Comment: Do you want to remove the whitespaces completely (e.g. in between separate words as well) or just normalize (e.g. replace multiple whitespaces by a single one)? For the latter I'd go with `normalize-space()`.

Comment: I think I might need the ```<lb>``` as line breaks, but I'm not sure ... :-D 
I want to stem and lemmatize the text afterwards in Python 3. 
Furthermore, I aim to tackle the text with stylometry (also Python 3 -> nltk etc)

Comment: If you still need help on whether or why the intent with `strip-space` fails it will help us to tell if you add a minimal but representative sample of the input XML together with the transformation result the posted code gives you, the result you want/expect and some explanation/details on how you run that XSLT 2 stylesheet.

Comment: sorry, I am quarantined right now and relatively heavy hit with the virus, despite of three vaccinations  :-( will be back once I'm better ...